# ASP.NET convert dialog units (DLU) to pixels

Tags: asp.net, fonts, default

I'm working on a project where I need to convert a dialog specified using DLU (Dialog units) into pixels so I can layout the web form in ASP.Net.

Dialog Units are computed based on the currently selected dialog font.  Of course, the dialog controls are free to specify their own fonts, but, the dialog and all the controls are rendered based on the dialog font.

In ASP.NET is there a way to programmatically determine the default font used by the Page or Form?  That is, regardless of how or where this is specified, is there a mechanism that I can use to generically determine the font used by the ASP.NET page or form?

Thanks for the help!!